# Which basic probability theory formula do I use?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I am trying to do the last question shown in red. I would appreciate a walk through. I can understand that the answer is 1/6 by just using my eyes, but I want to use the formula.

I was given this formula but I would never get it to work:

> $\Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[A|B] \cdot \Pr[B]$

I found this but I don't see how it would give me the correct answer:

> $\Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[A] \cdot \Pr[B]$

If someone walks through step by step I would be eternally grateful. It is possible that all of these formulas are the incorrect ones to use...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our sample space is the six possible outcomes $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ that occur when a six-sided die is thrown.

The event $X = \text{even}$ occurs when the throw results in an even number, which is $\{2, 4, 6\}$.

The event that $Y = c$ occurs when the throw results in a number divisible by $3$, which is $\{3, 6\}$.

Since each possible outcome of a fair die is equally likely,
$$\Pr(X = \text{even}) = \frac{|\{2, 4, 6\}|}{|\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}|} = \frac{3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$$
and 
$$\Pr(Y = c) = \frac{|\{3, 6\}|}{|\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}|} = \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$$
The event that $X = \text{even}$ and $Y = c$ occurs when a $6$ is obtained.  Hence, 
$$\Pr(X = \text{even} \wedge Y = c) = \frac{|\{6\}|}{|\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}|} = \frac{1}{6}$$
The conditional probability that $Y = c$ given that $X = \text{even}$ is
$$\Pr(Y = c \mid X = \text{even}) = \frac{\Pr(X = \text{even} \wedge Y = c)}{\Pr(X = \text{even})} = \frac{|\{6\}|}{|\{2, 4, 6\}|} = \frac{1}{3}$$
where we take the event that $X = \text{even}$ as our sample space.

Therefore, we have 
$$\Pr(X = \text{even} \wedge Y = c) = \Pr(Y = c \mid X = \text{even})\Pr(X = \text{even}) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$$

The rule that $\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A \mid B)\Pr(B)$ always applies.  The rule $\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$ only applies when events $A$ and $B$ are independent, meaning that the occurrence of one event does not affect the probability the other event will occur.  In this case, you can verify that the events $\Pr(X = \text{even})$ and $P(Y = c)$ are independent, but that is not always the case.

Comment: That was a fantastic answer, I really appreciate you showing me the Pr[A n B] = Pr[A|B] * Pr[B] formula that I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just getting confused by the logical operator. The question is asking for the probability that $X(\omega)=even$, and $Y(\omega)=c$ are true. $X(\omega)=even$ is true for $\omega\in \{2,4,6\}$, and $Y(\omega)=c$ is true when $\omega\in \{3,6\}$. Replace the logical statements with their set counterparts and you replace the logical operator with the set operator.
$$Pr(\omega \in \{2,4,6\} \cap \omega\in \{3,6\})=Pr(\omega=\{6\})=\frac{1}{6}
$$

The probability of the intersection can be done directly, so the first formula you linked isn't necessary, and the second is only true if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: I understand in this case it can be done directly because it's a simple example, but in the future I might need to use the formula because I get asked a harder question...?